# NGINX server block enabled but website returns 404 not found error

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-location, nginx-config, php-7.2

I have setup a Virtual Box guest machine running Ubuntu Server 18.0.4. I am trying to setup a test environment on my local system for a Wordpress website running on the LEMP stack. Followed some articles on the net and set up php7.2-fpm and nginx server alongwith mysql community edition. The LEMP setup seems to be fine as I have validated it with a test file containing phpinfo function. A dummy static ip address has been configured on the virtual box guest for testing purposes.

There are two server blocks in NGINX - default, which points to phpinfo and knowhow.com which points to the intended Wordpress website. The symbolic link is present in the sites-enabled directory and the knowhow.com file is setup in the sites-available directory. However, when I try to access the Wordpress site with /knowhow.com, I get a 404 Not Found error.

Did some digging around and it appears that some of the re-write rules in the knowhow.com config file might not be correct. I have no clue as to what should be the correct format. I want to access my website. Hence, all requests should ideally go to index.php. The contents of the knowhow.com config file are provided below. Can someone please help?

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/knowhow.com/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name knowhow.com www.knowhow.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where was your test phpinfo file located on disk, and what URL did you use to get to it?

Comment: /var/www/html/. I accessed it as static-ip-ipaddress/info.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue! Actually, it was never an issue in the first place. The configuration file is correctly defined. Only, the means of accessing the website was incorrect. I was trying to access the site as static-ip-address/knowhow.com from my local host machine (outside the vm). I should have simply accessed the site as knowhow.com or www.knowhow.com. Using the ip address was incorrect since the server block file (knowhow.com) shall automatically redirect the web request to the appropriate website root path on the target server. I had already updated my /etc/hosts file to point to the static IP address for knowhow.com and www.knowhow.com. Silly me!

Sorry for all the confusion. My setup is working as intended. Cheers!